# PyInstaller Orange3 __main__ Python script with call to script in different folder not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, orange, python-standalone

I am trying to run `orange` (forked as `orange3-master` and downloaded from https://github.com/biolab/orange3) with the following script `run.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    os.chdir('orange3-master/Orange/canvas')
    os.system('python __main__.py')
```

where in Anaconda prompt, running `python run.py` **allows** me to open up `orange`.

Now, as using `PyInstaller` to make `orange` into a standalone program seems quite an impossible feat for me at the moment, I tried the following:

1. Run `pyinstaller run.py`.
2. In `dist/run/` (the output folder of `pyinstaller`), copy over `orange3-master` into the same directory as `run.exe`, then run `run.exe`.

However, it does not seem to work as running `run.exe`, the window closes in a split second, and I am unable to observe any error messages.

Some insights and recommendations will be of great help...

Comment: Orange3 already has the executives posted on their website for [Windows](https://orange.biolab.si/download/#windows), and [OSX](https://orange.biolab.si/download/#macos). If you still need to do create an executive with `pyinstaller`, I would look to see you are not missing any hidden imports.

Comment: Here is the build bash script for [Windows](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/66b68aba1ed811193fb3f6e8231571b2368f4439/scripts/windows/build-win-installer.sh), and here is the build bash script for [OSX](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/66b68aba1ed811193fb3f6e8231571b2368f4439/scripts/macos/build-macos-app.sh).

Comment: @FelipeFaria Thanks for the feedback. I'll let you know in a bit once I have tried your suggestion, whether it is successful or not :)

Comment: @FelipeFaria I can't seem to run the bash script.. Upon clicking on it to run, as soon as the window opens, it closes. Am I doing it wrongly? Also does executing this bash script output a standalone executable version of Orange3? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could just download the `.dmg` or `.exe` from the first link I sent, I think (and assume) that would make the most sense for you. If you are trying to make a modification and build from source, make sure you run the `.sh` file from Terminal.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to build from source, we would also need to see your `pyinstaller` command to be of help. :)